# swift question about "@escaping" inside class

Tags: ios, swift

I am a newbie and maybe this is a silly question but I need some help.
I have this code like below but I wonder that should I remove "@escaping" inside the checkSignedIn function.

```
Class A{
    public func checkSignedIn(complete: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        _ = Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession { (result) in
            do {
                let session = try result.get()
                complete(session.isSignedIn)
            } catch {
                 print("Fetch auth session failed with error - \(error)")
                complete(false)
           }
        }
    }
```

I imagine that using "@escaping" will escape the return value from closure if I assign complete() to a variable like below.

```
Class A{
    var complete: (() -> Void)?
    public func checkSignedIn(complete: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        _ = Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession { (result) in
            do {
                let session = try result.get()
                self.complete = complete(session.isSignedIn)
            } catch {
                print("Fetch auth session failed with error - \(error)")
                self.complete = complete(false)
           }
        }
    }
```

Then I can call A.complete again.

Am I wrong? I appreciate it if you teach me about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they won't be the same.

The `complete: @escaping (Bool) -> Void` defines this:

- a function (or a callback) that takes 1 argument (`Bool`), and returns nothing (`Void`). It's an equivalent of function that looks like this:

  ```
  func complete(_ value: Bool) { }
  ```
- this function escapes the scope of the function it's passed to, as it runs asynchronously (that's `@escaping` keyword meaning)

And then this function is called with `complete(session.isSignedIn)`, where `session.isSignedIn` is a boolean argument you pass in, just as function's definition states, and function returns nothing

The statement `self.complete = complete(session.isSignedIn)` won't compile:

- You defined `self.complete` as `(() -> Void)` type - that is a function or callback that takes no arguments, and returns nothing. It's an equivalent of function:

  ```
  func y() { }
  ```
- So `complete(session.isSignedIn)` returns `Void` type as we know. Assigning `Void` type to `(() -> Void)` type is not going to work.

If you want to save the escaping function / callback to be used elsewhere, you can do this:

```
// Make sure signature of the variable matches that of a function argument
var complete: ((Bool) -> Void)?

public func checkSignedIn(complete: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

    // Save callback at the start of the function
    self.complete = complete
    // Then continue to a asynch part of the code:
    _ = Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession { (result) in
        // Inside this callback, you still can use the function argument
        complete(session.isSignedIn)
    ...
}

// But in another function, you have to use self.complete, e.g.:
func x() {
    // Use saved callback. You don't have to say `self` here, just using it for clarity
    self.complete(true)
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. 
So I can’t remove it bcz it runs asynchronously inside “ Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession”. And escaping will keep the data exist here (checkSignedIn)